# How to create a topmost overlay which ignores mouse clicks, etc

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

I'd like to know how to setup a transparent overlay windown in Cocoa which can ignore mouse clicks (so that they pass through to whatever window is below).  The user should not be able to interact with the window with their mouse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Tell it to ignore mouse events.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/setIgnoresMouseEvents:)

Comment: Awesome.  Never saw that property!