# How to make a clickable through JFrame?

Tags: java, swift, swing, jframe

I want to emulate the ignoresMouseEvents functionality offered in Swift but using Java Swing (because I want to make an application that works at least on the most popular OS), that is, make a clickable through window (I know that functionality is used in Hellium (for mac)).

I want to basically create a semi transparent overlay showing some statistics while allowing the user to keep using his underneath programs, games, etc.

Related question in swift language: [How to create a topmost overlay which ignores mouse clicks, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570247/how-to-create-a-topmost-overlay-which-ignores-mouse-clicks-etc)

IgnoreMouseEvents property: (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/setIgnoresMouseEvents:)

Comment: Use the [GlassPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) Luke!

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy I'm not sure if I didn't explain myself well, but what I want to do isn't to be able to see the root panel of the application, what I want to see (and be able to click buttons and other UI elements inside) is the window that is right **underlying** my application's window, what I believe can't be achievable using the java GlassPane. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: GlassPane is a transparent layer over a Window, which can contain any opaque elements. The panel under the GlassPane is still clickable. So you can place a semitransparent image on the GlassPane and your application in the ContentPane will receive all mouse and key events.